# Azure App Service - update .NET Core runtime

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I have an App Service on Azure Cloud for my .NET Core Web application. I decided to update my solution to .NET Core SDK to version 2.1.101 with runtime in version 2.0.6. When I try to start my application on Azure App Service, I get error which tells me that I can not run my application because of missing runtime in version 2.0.6. The highest installed version on Azure is 2.0.5.

The question is how can I install the newest version of .NET Core SDK (2.1.101)?

I tried with Site Extensions (Kudu) and run PowerShell scripts, but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my test, **currently the installed version on Azure is 2.0.6**. You can verify this by going to the Console and running ‘dotnet –info’. It should look like this:

[image]

We could also update the .NET Core runtime with *Azure App Service site extension*

[image]

In your case, if you publish it with VS,I recommond that you could check the [Remove additional files at destination] button during republish. That will remove the files existing in the WebApp before upload the files.

[image]

Comment: extensions is not available for Linux apps

Answer (score 1):

You can change NetCore Runtime on Configuration -> General settings -> Major version = [Select Net code version] and Save Changes.

You can check the net core version on Development Tools -> SSH. Though there is no dotnetsdk so dotnet --info won't run.

[image]